# leaflet popup and label going outside map division

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I am using popup on leaflet markers and using background as an image of fix size. Whenever the marker is placed on corner of map and then I click on marker to show pop-up ,it moves the complete map slightly for fraction of second and then the popup message goes outside the map screen. How to resolve this.

```
var content = 'Hi everybody I am here. How are you? Please resolve this.';
    L.marker([-67, 265.5]).bindPopup(content).addTo(map);
    L.marker([-21.5, 99.5]).bindPopup(content).addTo(map);
```

I have created a fiddle for the same :-

[Inline Link](http://jsfiddle.net/newBee_/88bdrzkr/9/)

Comment: Are you dynamically adding content to the pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand is that the map shouldn't auto pan when `popup` opens. The simple way is to set `autoPan:false` in your `popup` options. So, create the **marker** this way

```
L.marker([-67, 265.5]).bindPopup(content,{autoPan:false}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks @muzaffar but this approach only disables the autoPanning of map and the popup disappear behind map boundaries. Any other way to resolve this ?

Comment: do you want to see the popup as well?

Comment: Yes. I want to see the popup. One issue is resolved with autoPan: false . Now map is not repositioning itself. But Pop-up is hidded now. As I have used image of fix size thats why this problem is coming, otherwise pop-up itself handles the content and map panning. Kindly suggest if we can resolve this and show popup too. I have updated the fiddle also.

Comment: You have used the `setMaxBounds` to force the map not to show beyond the image. Would you comfortable to extend the bounds a bit more?

Comment: Yes please. We can try.